# How do I know the IP addresses of other computers in my network?

Tags: network

Say that I have two computers connected to the same network.
I know that from computer1 and file sharing enabled I can snoop around inside computer2.
But say that there is something interesting on computer2, which you access by typing localhost:9091 in safari. (e.g. transmission's web UI).
To access that I would have to type in the ip_address_of_computer2:9091 on computer1.

But how do I find out computer2's ip address without using computer2?

Comment: DO you know computer2's name?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Method #1**

The easiest way would be to access your network router's administration page. It will have information about any other devices on the network, including IP address.

**Method #2**

If you know the computer's network name you can `ping` it in the Terminal. It will return the computer's IP address.

**Method #3**

If you don't know the computer's network name, there's another trick you can do using `ping`. Find your IP address and your subnet mask. Both should be visible in the Network preference pane of System Preferences. Line up your IP address and your subnet mask, and replace any `0` values in the subnet mask with `255` in the same relative position of the IP address. For example, if you have the following IP address and subnet mask, respectively:

`192.168.1.151`

`255.255.255.0`

The `0` is in the last field of the subnet mask, so you replace the last field of the IP address with `255` and ping it: `ping 192.168.1.255`

You should get a response with the IP address of any device on the network capable of responding to pings.

**Method #4**

Last trick is to use the terminal command `arp -a`. This will show the IP and MAC address of all devices on the network that it knows about.

Last two tricks courtesy of [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/53277/2006/10/pingfind.html) Macworld article.

Comment: __Method # 4__ `arp -a` will work if, and only if, the Mac already successfully probed or was connected to a host. Try yourself by restarting your Mac and displaying the arp table. It will be almost empty. To populate that table you need to run something like a ping scan: `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24`

Comment: For some reason, pinging 192.168.1.255 returns the addresses from all Macs in the network, but none from the Linux machines ?!? Great tip though!

Comment: `ping SOME-PC -4` to forve the IPV4 resolving.

Comment: Does this work if your are pinging a windows computer?

Comment: I would list `arp -a` as method #1

Comment: I didn't know about method 3! Plus one for blowing my mind Michael you little IT devil you.

Comment: @cullub Yes, it works in windows. `ping adminPC` pings the adminPC computer and displays the IP address. And as Nakilon commented, `ping adminPC -4` displays the IPv4.

Comment: method #3 worked for me on mac osx, others did not.

Comment: Method #2 doesn't work on my mac... When I go to the *Finder > Network* I have two mac mini on my network but pinging them fails due to a *Unknown host* error...

Comment: arp -a worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

Type the command

```
  arp -a
```

This will show you all connections one by one.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for some devices. I'm not sure if it's because the devices aren't "listening" or if it's because of different OS's but I'm trying it now and `arp -a` is not picking up one of my linux boxes.

Comment: The first time you go to talk to another device on your computer, your computer needs to resolve IP -> MAC, and so it broadcasts "who has IP xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa?", and the owner of that IP responds (broadcasts) with "me!", and of course that packet has a source MAC in it.  If that transaction hasn't taken place while your device was on the network, it won't have an ARP entry for it.  Hence: not all devices show up in the ARP table, but may show up in other devices' ARP tables.

Answer (score 7):

**Q:** How do I know the **IP addresses** of other computers in **my network**?

**A lot of networks**

Well, first of all your computer is probably on a lot of *networks*. You can see this with the `ifconfig` command. There is a lot of info in there, but most of it is overwhelming, so I like to filter is like so:

```
$ ifconfig | grep -E '^[a-z0-9]|inet '

lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
en1: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 172.141.0.10 --> 172.141.0.9 netmask 0xffffffff
en5: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 169.254.146.193 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 169.254.255.255
bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.3.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.3.255
```

The first field of the left aligned lines are network interface names. You wifi is probably `en0`. My TunnelBlick VPN to AWS is `utun1`. My System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing created `bridge100` for the RaspberryPi I have getting internet from my MacBook Pro via my ethernet dongle.

**Assume IPv4**

Because you asked for *IP addresses* I assume IPv4 addresses are what you care about. I used "inet " (with a space) to block the "inet6" entries for IPv6. If you wanted IPv6 you probably know more about networking than I do and I should be asking you questions.

**Find the hosts**

Let's focus on that `bridge100` and bring you a little Google traffic. Lots of people run into this situation when they want to SSH or RDC into a headless computer (like a **RaspberryPi**) either on their network or tethered via **Internet Sharing**. It's especially difficult when you have no connection history (arp table) with the device. For this you can use `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.3.0/24`, which is the value of bridge100 inet (192.168.3.1) with the last digit replaced with "0/24". However, nmap isn't standard on OSX so we can install it with [homebrew](http://brew.sh).

```
$ brew install nmap
Warning: nmap-7.31 already installed

$ sudo nmap -sn 192.168.3.0/24
Password:

Starting Nmap 7.31 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-11-21 22:03 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.3.6
Host is up (0.00025s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.3.1
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 2.08 seconds
```

From that you can assume that my RaspberyPi got IP `192.168.3.6` for some reason. Last time I connected it I was on a different subnet and it got `192.168.2.3`. That nmap trick is a lot better than typing`ping 192.168.3.2` ... `ping 192.168.3.6` until you find it.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

This script should give you what you are looking for really quickly and requires to have nmap installed.
The advantage is that if your host does not reply to ping probes, nmap would still find the host while other tools will not.

```
#!/bin/bash
i="en1" # edit this to fit your Network interface
cidr=$(while read y; do echo ${y%.*}".0/$(m=0; while read -n 1 x && [ $x = f ]; do m=$[m+4]; done < <(ifconfig $i | awk '/mask/             {$4=substr($4,3); print $4}'); echo $m )"; done < <(ifconfig $i | awk '/inet[ ]/{print $2}') | head -n 1 | sed s/addr://g | sed 's/\/0//g')
myip=`ifconfig $i | grep "inet " | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}' | sed s/addr://g`
set -x
sudo nmap -n -T4 -PN -p9091 --exclude "$myip" "$cidr"
```

Store this script as `lookup.sh` and call it (with switch to english) with

```
LANG=c bash lookup.sh
```

Comment: How do you save and run that?

Comment: You paste this in TextEditor, and save and name this file "qnmap". You then move this file to /usr/bin (Hold Command+Shift+G, or Finder / Go / Go to folder : /usr/bin). open terminal, type "sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/qnmap". Type "qnmap" in the terminal and wait for the result.

Comment: Ok. I get this error: `/usr/bin/qnmap: line 2: =en1: command not found` It looks like the dollar sign before the `i` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Sorry Dan, my bad, the line should be : i="en1"

Comment: Cool. It works good.

Comment: Since we're scanning only port 9091, you can add -sV to the nmap command (service detection, fingerprinting), it won't take much longer. If this port does reply with a TCP ack flag, the -sV option would be more effective.

Comment: ERROR : error en1: error fetching interface information: Device not found
en1: error fetching interface information: Device not found
+ sudo nmap -n -T4 -PN -p9091 --exclude '' ''

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-08-24 23:50 IST
Failed to resolve "".
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.08 seconds

Answer (score 3):

There are a few other tools that have not been mentioned yet for discovering IP address information, assuming you have the host name and you are using mDNS (aka Bonjour in Mac environments).  Unless you have configured things differently, your local network names are in the form `host-name.local` so in your initial example you would be looking for `computer2.local`

The first:

```
    dscacheutil -q host -a name <host-name>.local
```

For example:

```
    % dscacheutil -q host -a name computer2.local
    name: computer2.local
    ip_address: 10.0.1.6
```

Another useful tool is `dig` (try `dig google.com` for example), which with a few special parameters can be used to query the mDNS nodes of your local network.

```
    % dig @224.0.0.251 -p 5353 <host-name>.local
    % dig @224.0.0.251 -p 5353 -x <ip-address>
```

To get just the IP address out of `dig` you can try:

```
    % dig +short @224.0.0.251 -p 5353 <host-name>.local
```

Comment: Good one bu it requires to know the IP address or computer multicastDNS name (.local).

Comment: BonjourBrowser is a nice GUI application for this.

Comment: @FlorianBidabe - Why do you say you need to know the IP address to use these commands?  These commands return the IP address of the named machine.  Yes, it is required to know the name of the target machine to use this method.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use netstat to show network addresses:

```
roger.moore@WKSTCAL0141 ~
$ netstat -n

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:11235        127.0.0.1:49184        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49155        127.0.0.1:49156        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49156        127.0.0.1:49155        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49184        127.0.0.1:11235        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:445     192.168.10.119:52624   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:1433    192.168.10.2:60866     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:1433    192.168.10.119:52775   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:3389    192.168.10.119:54473   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:49154   192.168.10.119:52796   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:49182   192.168.10.9:52230     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:49247   192.168.10.6:445       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:49432   192.168.10.4:1106      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:49440   192.168.10.4:1106      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:49451   192.168.10.6:1025      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:55100   192.168.10.2:445       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64558   192.168.10.20:135      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64559   192.168.10.20:49158    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64566   192.168.10.100:135     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64575   192.168.10.100:59811   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64581   192.168.10.41:139      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64582   192.168.10.3:5357      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64585   192.168.10.61:3910     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64587   192.168.10.65:3910     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64588   192.168.10.9:139       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64589   192.168.10.135:2869    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64593   192.168.10.6:135       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64594   192.168.10.6:1025      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.10.131:64599   192.168.10.100:59811   TIME_WAIT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the name using IP:
http://runakay.blogspot.com/2013/12/obtaining-computer-name-from-ip-address.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Wireshark and start a scan on your network card.

Filter the result by "nbns", and you will see the IP address in the upper window.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that works well for me is to use the `nmap` tool:

```
$ nmap -T4 -sP 192.168.0/24
```

the output looks like:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-08-08 16:15 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up (0.00061s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.5
Host is up (0.00035s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.31
Host is up (0.043s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.39
Host is up (0.0019s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.254
Host is up (0.0018s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 2.55 seconds
```

It only requires you to know the subnetwork (here `192.168.0`) that you wish to scan for.

On MacOS, this tool is easily installable using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew install nmap
```

while on most other systems like debian / ubuntu, you will need

```
$ apt install nmap
```

(I do not know about windows and I assume nobody would care on https://apple.stackexchange.com ...)