# Ping all the ip range of a local network

Tags: terminal, network

It is possible to reproduce the task via terminal as [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/) does, i.e. scan all the subnet?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19829/ping-all-ips-in-lan

Comment: It might be because my network vocabulary is basic, but your question is still quite unclear to me, especially with the current title which bears little relation with what you’re trying to achieve. I can’t really edit it unless I make *major* changes, so I’ll let you do it. Please be explicit about what you’re trying to achieve exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a network with 192.168.0.* IPs and a mask of 255.255.255.0, you can use

```
ping 192.168.0.255
```

Similarly, on the 128.0.* network, net mask 255.255.0.0

```
ping 128.0.255.255
```