# How to show the users and IP connected using GUI or command line?

Tags: macos, file-sharing, network

I have a MacBook Pro with El Capitan. I have followed the instructions to enable File Sharing, it is working through a new user account of Sharing Only type - let's name it RemoteUser. I can access it from other Windows users (7 and 8)

**Note** it only to work through LAN connection.

The purpose of this post is know:

How through a GUI and Command is it possible to show the users and ip connected to the account?

For example about a command/terminal report:

```
User         IP             [OS]
RemoteUser   192.168.1.8    Windows 7
RemoteUser   192.168.1.148  Windows 8
```

Where `RemoteUser` is the user that can access through many Windows machines in the *same* LAN and same time. Yes, the username and password is used to access from different machines in the same time.

If the `[OS]`info can be shown, it would be perfect.

Comment: [How do I know the IP addresses of other computers in my network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19783/)  [How to find devices on my local network through their IP address](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80370/) on this site and [How I can know the IP address of other users logged at the same remote machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24277/) on Unix.se can be helpful

Comment: Maybe a screen shot of the instructions you followed edited in to the question will get some more attention.

Comment: The figures are not included because is about how to enable "File Sharing", the question of the post is about how to see all the remote current connections. Anyway I am going to share the links from where I learned to enable and configure "File Sharing"